# Delayed Penalty with a Player Already in Penalty Box

Tags: rules, ice-hockey

We had a player already in the penalty box. With 11 seconds left in that penalty, the opposing team scored a goal while we had a delayed penalty.

It was my assumption that the delayed penalty is waived off since the opposing team scored and we still remained 1 player down for the 11 seconds.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## This is not correct.

If a team is already short-handed, the earliest minor penalty that its players are currently serving will be waived.

In the case of a goal being scored, the penalty with 11 seconds will be cancelled, and the penalty that was delayed will be served in full.

The only exception is that, if the existing penalty is a major or match penalty, it remains on the board, and the delayed penalty will be waived instead (because it would be the only, and therefore the earliest, minor penalty).

See IIHF Rulebook, Rule 114 *Delayed Penalty Call - Puck Control & Goals*, parts viii and ix for the exact wording that gives rise to this.

Comment: So would it be a good assumption that giving that the delayed penalty is considered at it's full time (2 minutes) the waived penalty would be the one with the least time remaining on it?

Comment: Since that would make it also the earliest one to have started, yes, it's effectively the same thing.

Comment: But if there's a 5min and a 2min, and let's say there 3:45 on the 5 remaining, it's the 2 that gets waved even if the 5 was called before? My NHL rulebook is rusty.

Comment: Correct, a major penalty can't be waived by a goal, so the principle of "earliest minor penalty gets cancelled" still applies.